# Find if a day (example sunday or monday) falls between two given days in Java

Tags: java, date

For example, 
If the input is sunday, let's say day = 1.

```
int day = 1;
```

Two days will be passed. Start date and End date. Let's say start date is monday and end date is wednesday, I want a method to return false.

The input day could be anything (Monday is 2, Tuesday is 3 etc)  and the start and end date could be anything.

Below is the snippet, I tried. But it is not accurate. Can someone please help?

```
   int day = 1; 
   // Will be 2 for monday, 3 for tuesday etc. 
   // Consider that the value of day is passed as parameter

  int startDayOfWeek = startDate.getCalendar().get (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
  int endDayOfWeek = endDate.getCalendar().get (Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);  
  LocalDate resStartDate = startDate;

  LocalDate resEndDate = resAvailabilityDetails.endDate)
  int diffBetweenStartEndDate = 
      Days.daysBetween (resStartDate, resEndDate).getDays();
  // If the Available_on is Thursday, and if the start date and end 
  // date, inclusive, do not overlap a Thursday, then do not show the
  // record. Similarly for other days of the week
  if (diffBetweenStartEndDate < 7 && ! (day >= startDayOfWeek || day <= endDayOfWeek)) {
       continue;
  }
```

Comment: *" Let's say start date is monday and end date is wednesday, I want a method to return false."* - Can you clearify this statement, that means you want it to always return `false`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek OP want false, because Sunday is not between Monday and Wednesday

Comment: @Andreas Correct. Thats my requirement. Return true is sunday is present between the start date and end date, else false

Comment: @Gurunathan What if start date or end date *is* Sunday?

Comment: Start < day < end

Comment: @Andreas It should return true

Comment: What if the start day is monday, and the end day is wednesday, just a week and 2 days later? Do you need to return true?

Comment: Startday is friday, endday is monday, sunday in between, right? No weeks considered, only days? Don't handle with Calender, then. And of course, in civilized countries, the week starts with monday, and for programmers, that is 0, so you can easily operate with modulo. :) But the question is open: The borders of the intrval belong on both sides to yes, so inRange (su, we, su) = true, and inRange (su, we, we) is true?

Comment: **Two days will be passed. Start date and End date.** Then **Consider that the value of day is passed as parameter** - so 3 parameters are passed, right? Then: You start with real dates, Y/M/D, and extract the day-of-week. But if the order is start < end is not evaluated. So any combination (Su, Su) ... (Su, Sa), (Mo, Su)...(Mo, Sa) ..., ..., ... (Sa, Sa) is possible. It will be of much surprise, if the interval is from Mo.10 to We.19 and day is Fr. (14) but not included - won't it? The naming is suboptimal too. startDayOfWeek sounds like Monday (EU) or Sunday (US), better: weekdayOfStart.

Comment: Are you using `LocalDate` and `Days` from Joda-Time?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It just requires comparing two integers:

```
int day = Calendar.Sunday; 
int startDayOfWeek = startDate.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int endDayOfWeek = endDate.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK); 

if(startDayOfWeek < day && endDayOfWeek > day) {
     //The given day is between the start and end days.
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you check if (startDayOfWeek < endDayOfWeek) prior to the current if statement? Because otherwise, a different set of conditions would apply.

Comment: The troublesome `Calendar` class is now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes. Their use in 2018 is ill-advised.

Comment: @Yokhen, you don't need to check that. It is already covered in the `if` statement I have there.

Comment: @BasilBourque, I am aware that `java.util.Date` and `java.time.*` classes are problematic in "some" sense. However, I haven't heard anything wrong about `java.util.Calendar` class. Nor do I find any information about its deprecation plan. Certainly Java 9 [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) doesn't indicate that.

Comment: @VHS The official Oracle Tutorial replaced the old tutorial using `Date`/`Calendar` with a new one using only *java.time* classes. Sun, Oracle, & the JSR community approved [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) with the express purpose of replacing the legacy date-time classes. Time to forget all about the wretched mess that is `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, & the related `java.sql` classes. They were a valiant attempt to handle date-time in a sophisticated manner for an industry that for too long ignored the problem. But they failed. Thus Joda-Time, and now java.time.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY , DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ) 
    .contains(
        myLocalDate.getDayOfWeek()
    )
```

## Details

Your Question is not clear, so perhaps I am misinterpreting. It seems like the aspect of sequence is a red herring, a distraction. Thinking in terms of “from/start” and “to/stop” for day-of-week is only confusing matters. You seem to care only if a specific date’s day-of-week happens to be a member of a set of desired day-of-week values.

For example, if you are defining “weekend”, don’t say “the days between Friday & Monday”. Just say “set of Saturday & Sunday”.

The *java.time* framework has classes for these purposes. Use them.

The `DayOfWeek` enum carries seven predefined objects, each for a day-of-week, Monday-Sunday.

The `EnumSet` class is an implementation of `Set` highly optimized for holding enum objects. This class is very fast, and uses very little memory.

Collect the day-of-week values you care about.

```
Set< DayOfWeek > dows = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY , DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ) ;
```

Get your date’s day-of-week.

```
DayOfWeek dow = myLocalDate.getDayOfWeek() ;
```

Ask if the set contains that day-of-week.

```
Boolean hit = dows.contains( dow ) ;
```

Among your codebase, pass these `DayOfWeek` enum and `Set` objects. Avoid using clumsy representations such as Strings like “Mo” and ambiguous integers like `1`.

You don’t even need a dedicated method as being suggested in the Question. As seen up top, you could just as easily get the job done in one or two lines of clear explicit code rather than call some other method.

You *can* use the idea of a range of day-of-week, but I see no advantage in your problem scenario.

But if you insist, you’ll need a clear definition of the week’s ordering. I suggest you follow the ISO 8601 standard week definition of starting on a Monday, running through Sunday, numbered 1-7. The `DayOfWeek` enum uses this standard definition.

```
Set< DayOfWeek > dows = EnumSet.range( DayOfWeek.MONDAY , DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY ) ;  // 3 days, Mon/Tues/Wed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want both start and end dates to be inclusive, the diff-between check should be comparing with 6, because if end date is 6 days after start date, they cover a full week, e.g. Monday -> Sunday.

You will of course also need to ensure that end date is not before start date.

Since day-of-week is a circular scale that rolls over at some point *(between Saturday and Sunday when using `Calendar`)*, you need to account for that.

If endDate > startDate, but endDayOfWeek < startDayOfWeek, then you should add 1 week (7 days) to the endDayOfWeek, to ensure it is >= startDayOfWeek.

Same for testDayOfWeek.

Instead of using `if` statements, always adding 7 and then using modulus 7, makes code simpler (smaller).

So, your tests are (pseudo-code):

```
if (endDate < startDate):
    return false
if (diff(startDate, endDate) >= 6)
    return true
return (testDoW + 7 - startDoW) % 7 <= (endDoW + 7 - startDoW) % 7
```

Comment: No, endDate < startDate means, in the interval Fr to Mo, Su is true and We is false.

Comment: @userunknown Really?? `startDate` = Feb 20, 2018, `endDate` = Feb 10, 2018, should mean that any days are covered? Note that `endDate` and `endDoW` is not the same thing (DoW = Day of Week).

Comment: Well, if I tell you, that I will fix my code between Friday and Monday - what might that mean? It's not unusual at all. Of course the statement is true, if I fix it on Friday, Saturday, Sunday or Monday - the borders of the interval can be disputed, but without agreed upon convention, I would include both. So yes, Su-Sa include the whole week, and so do Mo-Su, Tu-Su ... Sa-Fr. And imho, we only have weekdays, no 8, 9, .. 13 or -4, -3 - whether counting from 0 or 1 isn't quiet clear, as the whole question is pretty confus.

Comment: @userunknown I have no idea what point you are trying to make. I already know all this, and my answer handles ranges like Fri-Mon. The first `if` statement is not about **weekdays**, like Friday. It's about **dates**, such as February 2, 2018.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what the real question is, but my impression is, that Gurunathan uses the Dates just as source for Weekdays, but throws away the concrete Dates. He just wants to operate on Su...Sa. But then there is this 4th Date, resAvailabilityDetails.endDate and a suspicious continue in the nowhereland...  :)

Comment: @userunknown Not true. The actual dates matter, because question code was explicitly checking to see if dates were 7 days apart, because if they are, they cover at least a full week, and all weekdays are then covered, for an unconditional return value of `true`. The **dates** matter, so good coding defines rules even for when dates are reversed, whether always `false`, or maybe throwing `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: The days, 7 days apart, are date A and C, but the weekdays are date A and B. B and C might be the same date or might be not. We don't know. It's a mess.

Comment: Clever one @Andreas!

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it right, now, but maybe somebody likes to copy my testcode to check his own solution or to improve the tests:

```
String [] daya = {"Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"}; 
List <String> days = Arrays.asList (daya);

boolean dayInRange (String check, String from, String to) {
  int f = days.indexOf (from);
  int t = days.indexOf (to);
  int c = days.indexOf (check);
  if (f < 0 || t < 0 || c < 0)  {
    System.out.print ("  invalid date! ");
    return false; 
  }

  if (f < t) {
    System.out.print ("ordinary between");
    return (f <= c && c <= t); // ordinary ordering 
  }
  if (f == t) {
    System.out.print ("   start=end    ");
    return (f == c); // From-to is same date, 
  }
  if (f > t) {
    System.out.print ("weekend passing ");
    return (t <= c || c <= f); // range over the weekend border 
  }
  System.out.print (" no match ");
  return false;
} 


void check (boolean expected, String x, String f, String t, String msg) {
    if (expected == dayInRange (x, f, t)) 
        System.out.println ("fine +: (" + x + ") in " + f + "-"  + t + " :\t"  + msg);
    else 
        System.out.println ("bad---: (" + x + ") " + f + "-"  + t + " :\t"  + msg);
}

check (true,  "Mo", "Mo", "Th", "on left boundary");
check (true,  "Th", "Mo", "Th", "on right boundary");
check (false, "We", "Mo", "Tu", "Wednsday past Tuesday (and Mo)"); 
check (false, "Mo", "We", "Fr", "Mo before We (and Fr)") 
check (true,  "We", "Mo", "Th", "ordinary mo-_-(we)-th");
check (true,  "We", "We", "We", "one day interval, hit");
check (false, "Fr", "We", "We", "one day interval, past");
check (false, "Mo", "We", "We", "one day interval, too early");
check (true,  "We", "Fr", "Th", "every day should fit between Fr and Th") 
check (false, "Yo", "Mo", "Th", "no such date");
```

This is clearly a case, where Testcode is very helpfull. But we need feedback from the algorithm too, to check which test produced the result. My first implementation didn't reveal that.

Jshell output for the tests:

```
-> check (true,  "Mo", "Mo", "Th", "on left boundary");
ordinary betweenfine +: (Mo) in Mo-Th : on left boundary

-> check (true,  "Th", "Mo", "Th", "on right boundary");
ordinary betweenfine +: (Th) in Mo-Th : on right boundary

-> check (false, "We", "Mo", "Tu", "Wednsday past Tuesday (and Mo)"); 
ordinary betweenfine +: (We) in Mo-Tu : Wednsday past Tuesday (and Mo)

-> check (false, "Mo", "We", "Fr", "Mo before We (and Fr)") 
ordinary betweenfine +: (Mo) in We-Fr : Mo before We (and Fr)

-> check (true,  "We", "Mo", "Th", "ordinary mo-_-(we)-th");
ordinary betweenfine +: (We) in Mo-Th : ordinary mo-_-(we)-th

-> check (true,  "We", "We", "We", "one day interval, hit");
   start=end    fine +: (We) in We-We : one day interval, hit

-> check (false, "Fr", "We", "We", "one day interval, past");
   start=end    fine +: (Fr) in We-We : one day interval, past

-> check (false, "Mo", "We", "We", "one day interval, too early");
   start=end    fine +: (Mo) in We-We : one day interval, too early

-> check (true,  "We", "Fr", "Th", "every day should fit between Fr and Th") 
weekend passing fine +: (We) in Fr-Th : every day should fit between Fr and Th

-> check (false, "Yo", "Mo", "Th", "no such date");
  invalid date! fine +: (Yo) in Mo-Th : no such date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @return true if {@code test} is between {@code start}
 *          and the following (or same) {@code end}, inclusive  
 */
public static boolean isBetween(DayOfWeek start, DayOfWeek test, DayOfWeek end) {
    // is start before end?
    if (start.getValue() < end.getValue()) {
        return start.getValue() <= test.getValue() && test.getValue() <= end.getValue();
    } else if (start.equals(end)) {
        return test.equals(start);
    } else {
        // end is in the following week
        return start.getValue() <= test.getValue() || test.getValue() <= end.getValue();
    }
}
```

I am using `DayOfWeek` from `java.time` because I always use `java.time` for my date operations, so this is the type I would naturally have in such a situation. If you are using Joda-Time, do something similar with the `int` you get from `LocalDate.getDayOfWeek()`. The algorithm is indifferent to whether the week begins on Sunday or Monday, you don’t need to care. I recommend you stay off the old `Calendar` class, it’s long outdated, and today we have so much better.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the given int values for **Java's** `DayOfWeek`. A clean function will take the params in the form of the `DayOfWeek` enum.

Using the int values, you can write a function that handles the cases in which `start <= input` and `start > input`. (This fun is written in `Kotlin` btw)

```
fun isDayOfWeekInBetween(dayOfWeek: DayOfWeek, start: DayOfWeek, end: DayOfWeek): Boolean {
    if (start.value <= dayOfWeek.value) {
        return dayOfWeek.value <= end.value || end.value <= start.value
    }
    return end.value <= start.value && end.value >= dayOfWeek.value
}
```